# Django two foreign Keys in model, how to dynamically change options?

Tags: django, forms

i have two foreign keys in one table, but when i add a new record, i want that my ForeignKey "Modelo" only shows the one with the id of the ForeignKey "Marca" ... i want to create a Dynamically Select on depends of what i select from the first ForeignKey...

Here's my code

```
class Marca(models.Model):
    idmar = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    marca=models.CharField(max_length=30)   

class Modelo(models.Model):
    idmod = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    idmar=models.ForeignKey(Marca)
    modelo=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

In This model i want to get the idmod that contains the id from idmar

```
class Copiadora(models.Model):
    idcop = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    idequipo=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    idmar=models.ForeignKey(Marca)
    idmod=models.ForeignKey(Modelo)
    noserie=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

or do i have to use, javascript? or ajax? whats the best solution ...

First Post... sorry if not clear

Comment: There is no built in approach to this - you will need to user ajax (or a 3rd party library)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what is required? Please give a brief example (with data) as well...

Answer (score 0):

[Django smart selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) will help you